# Kivy App screen is not appearing while running the app

Tags: python, kivy

This message is showing and no app screen is coming. Please help me out here. Do I have to install some dependencies?

```
[INFO] [Logger ] Record log in C:\Users\sachin\.kivy\logs\kivy_16-05-24_56.txt
[INFO] [Kivy   ] v1.9.1
[INFO] [Python ] v3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO] [Factory] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO] [Image  ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO] [Text   ] Provider: sdl2
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Is this only on android or does it also happen on your local PC? Can you show us some code? Everything seems to be normal, there are no errors, are you sure your code should show something?

Comment: This message indicates that everything is working fine. Does your code definitely actually start an app?

Comment: the logged text should be formatted as `code`

Comment: @syntonym look at the path, that's no android. The tag was misused.

Comment: Do you have `<AppClass>().run()` at the end of your file, where `<AppClass>` is the name from `class <AppClass>(App):`? Seems to me only like an import&exit. Provide code/example to make it possible to answer.

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr You are right.

Comment: it is happening on my local PC. i have just started using kivy for the app development. and this the code I'm using. and there is no app window is coming after i run my program.                                                          import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label


class SimpleKivy(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Hello World ")


if __name__=="_main_":
    SimpleKivy().run()

Comment: throw away if at the end, just `SimpleKivy().run()` and try if it runs.. if yes, either you have wrong name of a file or misspelled something in if.

Comment: thank you @keyWeeusr 2. there was error in if statement.

Comment: @SachinKumar Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Author's code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label
class SimpleKivy(App):
    def build(self): return Label(text="Hello World ")
if _name__=="_main": SimpleKivy().run()  # bad if statement
```

Throw away `if` at the end, just `SimpleKivy().run()` and try if it runs.. if yes, either you have wrong name of a file or misspelled something in if.

*For future cases use it like this:*

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    SimpleKivy().run()
```